# Unity Emission Lighting Not Effecting Imported Objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lighting

I have an emissive material with HDR of 1.5 applied to the sphere below (3).

Cube 1 is a Unity primitive.

Cube 2 is a 3D studio max primitive with a material applied after importing to Unity.

Mesh 4 is a 3D studio max object imported with several materials applied in 3D studio max.

1, 2, and 4 all have the same material. All 4 objects are static.

Emission from the sphere has some effect on Cube 2, but not as much as Cube 1 and not at all in the shadow. It has no effect on Mesh 4.

The effect of the sphere on Cube 1 is what I'm going for, but only seems to work on primitives created in Unity. What am I doing wrong?

note that the material texture looks different due to scaling/tiling. It is the same wood grain material on all 3 objects.

[image]

[image]

In this image, I've maxed out the HDR to illustrate how the light effects/doesn't effect the different objects.

[image]

Comment: It says there also `This GameObject has overlapping UVs. Please enable 'Generate Lightmap UVs' or fix in your modelling package.` Might this be related? It also already had a static lightmap .. maybe it just has to be re-baked?

Comment: Thanks @derHugo. I have auto baking on. Regarding the error message, the same message comes up on the Unity primitive. I just created another new cube in Unity to verify, and after selecting the static checkbox, without even applying a material, the same error comes up.